# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1258291200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) and My site down in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1258291200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Price/Configurable Price Resolver.php on line 65 in Magento 2.3
After this error my site show page without header and foter.

I have already increase memory in .htaccess  and php.ini file.
memory_limit=1024M

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase memory_limit like 2048M, and if still it will not resolved please make it 4096M.
It will definitely resolved your issue.
One more thing if you are debugging using print Magento's default data objects it will also causes this type of error.